# Get id of dynamic added element in onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is a function that is created a html elements on page when document is ready. I have to create `onclick()` event on that elements and use there an element id.

My code is:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    addNewElementToContainer();
});

function addNewElementToContainer(){
 $("#myContainer").append('<div onclick="myClickEvent(this.id)" value="1" >Click me</div>');
}

function myClickEvent(id){
    alert("ID: " + id);
}
```

The `id` is set correctly (check it on page inspector) but the result is wrong -  `"ID: "`. So it looks like the id is empty.

How is it possible to solve that problem?

@UPDATE
Html file is:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="myContainer"><div>
    </body>

    <script>
        $('document').ready(function(){
            addNewElementToContainer();
        });
        function addNewElementToContainer(){
            $("#myContainer").append('<div onclick="myClickEvent(this.id)" value="1" >Click me</div>');
        }
        function myClickEvent(id){
            alert("ID: " + id);
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I fell like you didnt give us the whole code.
cos it dosent make sence what you posted here.

Comment: @Talg123 I added whole html file

Comment: I`m not sure what does it suppose to be myClickEvent(this.id) 
what do u think that "this.id" will give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just give the id and value for your Html element as below:

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
            addNewElementToContainer();
        });
        function addNewElementToContainer(){
            $("#myContainer").append('<div onclick="myClickEvent(this.id, this)" id="id1" data-value="1" >Click me</div>');
        }

function myClickEvent(id, obj){
            alert("ID: " + id);
            val = obj.getAttribute('data-value');
            alert(val);
        }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="myContainer"><div>
    </body>
    </script>
</html>
```

Comment: it works! Is there any way to get the element `value` as well?

Comment: Yes , I have edited the same post with value as well  now. Please check. For this you can use "data-value" element inside div and pass the object, and get it from that.

Answer (score 1):

> it works! Is there any way to get the element value as well?

yes, eg with jquery

`$(this).attr('value');`

Answer (score 0):

The context "this" has no property id set.